# What should I call a "todo" section?

Tags: choix-de-mot

I use an app for tracking what tasks I have to do and have done. I have a list called "todo" which I'd like to rename to be in french.

**What should it be called?** À fait? Faire?

Comment: https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/to-do+list.html

Comment: Not a translation, but personally I always use "Tout doux". x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***À faire*** is the correct translation.
You can also call it a ***liste de tâches***.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the expression ***pense-bête***. Maybe a bit old-fashioned, and possibly unpleasant, implying the user is dumb (*bête*) and needs it to think (*penser*).